# Differences in making a thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, conventions

I've seen several different ways to make a new Thread, but there's one way I've seemingly forgot about, and can't find many examples of it, and I'd like to compare it to another way:

This one I've seemed to forgotten about, I'm not sure if it requires to implement Runnable or not:

```
new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            System.out.println("running");
        }
    };
```

vs.

```
new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            System.out.println("Running");
        }
    });
```

Differences? Advantages disadvantages?

and when should I make an anonymous Thread, vs when to implement Runnable?

Comment: There's a prominent question, have you checked? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just saw, you accepted an answer, there after also I could not resist myself to provide my answer here.

**There is no sign of `Thread` subclass in your question, so there is noting to do with extending `Thread` or implementing `Runnable`, here.**

**Here you are just creating `Thread` object in two different manners, by using two different constructors.** In the second case, you are using [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Thread.java#Thread.%3Cinit%3E%28java.lang.Runnable%29) version of constructor for creating a new `Thread` instance. You are basically providing an external `Runnable` object to run its run method, when your instantiating thread runs.

[Here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Thread.java#Thread.run%28%29) is the source code of `run` method, here you will see that in the, `run` method of `Thread`, `target`'s `run` method is called, in case you provided it!

There is nothing to do with the performance. Which constructor will you use, is a matter of your use case. In simplest case, we generally do not need or use the second one.

For resolving any confusion, you can just go through the source code!

Comment: `There is no sign of Thread subclass in your question` --- `new Thread() {...}` creates a subclass of `Thread`. You are not aware of that?

Answer (score 1):

No appreciable difference if you create `anonymous classes` as you have provided in the question.

However difference between `Thread t = new SubClassOfThread();` and `Thread t = new Thread(new ClassImplementingRunnable)` is that

since `SubClassOfThread` extends `Thread` you cannot use it to extend any other class where as in case of `Runnable` you can make it extend one more Class.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the second way because it decouples the `Runnable` from the `Thread`.

The first way creates a new anonymous class that extends `Thread`. But you only should extend another class in the sense of "is a". In your example this would be ok, but if the responsibility of the run method grows, it would be cleaner to say that your function is `Runnable`, but not that its main purpose is to be a `Thread`.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice states that you should generally favor composition over inheritance. Applied to your question, your first example makes a subclass of `Thread` and overrides its `run` method (*inheritance*), and the second example instantiates the standard `Thread` class, passing it a `Runnable` with the `run` method implemented as needed (*composition*).

Why the latter is a best practice comes to light when you manage to inadvertently involve a member of `Thread` (a method or field) in your `run` method due to a typo or other oversight. Once that happens, you'll have a ride finding the cause of possibly very weird behavior.